# Natural problems believed to be in EQP but not BPP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Are there any “natural” problems in $\mathsf{EQP}$ that are believed to not be in $\mathsf{BPP}$?  If so, what are some exapmles?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/40787